# ggplot2 barplot breaks when position = "dodge" used

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm currently working on a COVID-19 Germany Shiny App for an University Project.
I'm trying to make a barplot that shows the daily infection numbers of different regional levels of Germany. This is not a specific problem with Shiny App, it's more ggplot. I reproduced the problem without the Shiny App enviornment.
My basic Code is the following:

```
require(tidyverse)
library(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)
require(zoo)
library(zoo)


data <- read_csv("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/dd4580c810204019a7b8eb3e0b329dd6_0.csv")

## Data Coding data Datensatz
data$Meldedatum <- ymd_hms(data$Meldedatum)
data$Meldedatum <- date(data$Meldedatum)

# Label Deutschland

data$label_de <- paste("Deutschland")

# Label Deutschland - Alter

data$label_de_age <- paste(data$label_de, data$Altersgruppe)

# Label Bundesland Alter

data$label_bl_age <- paste(data$Bundesland, data$Altersgruppe)

# Label SK/LK Alter

data$label_sklk_age <- paste(data$Landkreis, data$Altersgruppe)

#Data Long
data_long <- data[c( "Meldedatum", "AnzahlFall","Bundesland", "Landkreis" ,"label_de_age", "label_bl_age", "label_sklk_age")]
data_long$Deutschland <- "Deutschland"

data_long<- pivot_longer(data_long, -c( Meldedatum, AnzahlFall), values_to = "Gebiet")

data_long<- data_long[c("Meldedatum", "AnzahlFall", "Gebiet")]
```

The specific new labels for the column `data_long$Gebiet` are important for my shiny App.
Now if I want to plot the daily infection numbers of e.g. "Deutschland" (Germany) and "Bayern" (Bavaria) without `position = "dodge"`, my graph looks like the following, which is fine at first.

```
# Plot Deutschland and Bayern
ggplot(data =  subset(data_long, Gebiet %in% c("Deutschland", "Bayern" )), 
       mapping = aes(
         x= Meldedatum,
         y= AnzahlFall,
         fill = Gebiet
       ) )+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: Plot1 without dodge]

But if I now add the line `position = "dodge"` to `geom_bar()` my plot breaks. And looks like the following.

```
# Plot Deutschland and Bayern with dodge
ggplot(data =  subset(data_long, Gebiet %in% c("Deutschland", "Bayern" )), 
       mapping = aes(
         x= Meldedatum,
         y= AnzahlFall,
         fill = Gebiet
       ) )+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image: Plot2 with dodge]

Does somebody know why this happens and how to fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the interest of the *minimal* part of [mcve], if the question isn't about reshaping your data, just post a sample of whatever data frame you're trying to plot that's enough to recreate the issue. That saves us from downloading a file of unknown size, plus a dozen or so lines of code, and helps you focus in on what the actual problem might be

Comment: Thanks for the advice camille. Since this was my first question on stackoverflow I will follow it in my future posts. And thanks for editing my Pictures.

Comment: You can [edit] the post to clean it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have multiple observations per date. Therefore you get multiple bars per date (and of course region) when using `position="dodge"`. To solve this issue aggregate your data by date and region before plotting, e.g. by using `count(Meldedatum, Gebiet, wt = AnzahlFall)` which will add a new variable (named `n` by default) to your df with the sum of cases per date and region:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)
library(zoo)


data <- read_csv("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/dd4580c810204019a7b8eb3e0b329dd6_0.csv")

## Data Coding data Datensatz
data$Meldedatum <- ymd_hms(data$Meldedatum)
data$Meldedatum <- date(data$Meldedatum)

# Label Deutschland

data$label_de <- paste("Deutschland")

# Label Deutschland - Alter

data$label_de_age <- paste(data$label_de, data$Altersgruppe)

# Label Bundesland Alter

data$label_bl_age <- paste(data$Bundesland, data$Altersgruppe)

# Label SK/LK Alter

data$label_sklk_age <- paste(data$Landkreis, data$Altersgruppe)

#Data Long
data_long <- data[c( "Meldedatum", "AnzahlFall","Bundesland", "Landkreis" ,"label_de_age", "label_bl_age", "label_sklk_age")]
data_long$Deutschland <- "Deutschland"

data_long<- pivot_longer(data_long, -c( Meldedatum, AnzahlFall), values_to = "Gebiet")

data_long<- data_long[c("Meldedatum", "AnzahlFall", "Gebiet")] 

data_long %>% 
  count(Meldedatum, Gebiet, wt = AnzahlFall) %>% 
  filter(Gebiet %in% c("Deutschland", "Bayern")) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(
         x= Meldedatum,
         y= n,
         fill = Gebiet
       ))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking over my code even if this dataframe was quite huge. For my next questions I will use minimal reproducible examples so you don't have to download this much data just to give a quick advice. Thanks for the Help!